# React Native Custom Hook call with Parameter Invalid Hook Call

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to use my custom hook when onPress is tapped, it receives a parametar but after calling it it returns invalid hook call. I want to call my UPDATED custom hook by calling a function that would pass the argument, I mean parametar, to my custom hook so it loads the chosen url. My code:

```
    const PokemonListItem: React.FC<PokemonItemProps> = ({dataPokemon}) => {
      const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<IPokemonAttributes>();
      const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    
        const pokemonsData = (chosenPokemonUrl: string) => {
            const {data, isLoading} = usePokemonAttributes(chosenPokemonUrl);
            setPokemon(data);
            setModalVisible(true);
            console.log(data);
          };
        
          return (
            <View>
//this DOESNT work
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pokemonsData(dataPokemon.url)}>
                <Text style={styles.pokemonListItem}>{dataPokemon.name}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        };
```

My custom hook:

```
const usePokemonAttributes = (pokemonUrl: string): IusePokemonAttributes => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  //const [shouldRun, setShouldRun] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState<IPokemonAttributes>();
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  // const handleTap = () => {
  //   setShouldRun(!shouldRun);
  // };

  const fetchingPokemonAttributes = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${urls.baseUrl + pokemonUrl}`, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(await json);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingPokemonAttributes();

    return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, [pokemonUrl]);
  return {data, error, isLoading};
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The Problem

It's not working because your custom hook is not in the `PokemonListItem` component's body. With current implementation, it's a bit tricky to call the `fetchingPokemonAttributes` from the `PokemonListItem` component.

##### Solution

Instead of calling another function to call the `fetchingPokemonAttributes`, call it directly with `onPress` action.

To achieve this, we need to export the `fetchingPokemonAttributes` from the custom hook to use it in `PokemonListItem`:

**First**, in the custom hook:

```
const usePokemonAttributes = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<IPokemonAttributes>();
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  const fetchingPokemonAttributes = async (pokemonUrl) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${urls.baseUrl + pokemonUrl}`, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json); // -----> also remove the await from here !!
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, [pokemonUrl]);

  return {data, error, isLoading, fetchingPokemonAttributes};
};
```

**Note:** since the `fetchingPokemonAttributes` need the `url`, I removed the `pokemonUrl` from the custom hook and pass it directly with the `fetchingPokemonAttributes` function.

**Note:** you added a `await` keyword in `setData` method. it's redundant.

Second,, in the `PokemonListItem`, we need to call `fetchingPokemonAttributes` with `onPress` action. (don't forget to pass the URL here)

```
const PokemonListItem: React.FC<PokemonItemProps> = ({dataPokemon}) => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<IPokemonAttributes>();
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  
  const {data, error, isLoading, fetchingPokemonAttributes} = usePokemonAttributes();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(data.length > 0 && !error) {
      setPokemon(data);
      setModalVisible(true);
    }
  }, [data, error])
        
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchingPokemonAttributes(dataPokemon.url)}>
        <Text style={styles.pokemonListItem}>{dataPokemon.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Now, with the `onPress` action, the `fetchingPokemonAttributes` will invoke and the custom hook returns `data`, `error`, `isLoading`. Now time to use them in the `PokemonListItem` with `useEffect` hook.

As you see, I used some rules to check the conditions before updating the `pokemon`, you can define your custom condition here according to your requirement and `data` type.

Comment: I solved it practially the same way and I came here to write it all and then I see this:D  Definetly a corrent answer as it helped me. I didnt know about redundant await but it makes sense because of nature of useState. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call
`const {data, isLoading} = usePokemonAttributes(chosenPokemonUrl);`
in pokemonsData const you have to call it in PokemonListItem

Comment: But I cant call it without parametar chosenPokemonUrl, how can I call it outside pokemonsData when pokemonsData gives me the needed url for custom hook?